# Send a message to object in 10 seconds

Tags: ios, ios4

I want to send message to object in every 10 seconds. I want to do something like this `[object message];`.How can I do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`NSTimer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html). Example.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 
                                 target:object 
                               selector:@selector(message)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

You are recommended to use a selector of the form `- (void)timerMethod:(NSTimer *)timer` but this works too.